# Looking for a Better Way to Iterate in ASP.NET Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

I'm building a conference page that includes two levels. That is, a Speaker Track Level and a Speaker Level.  The code is ASP.NET Core (MVC Razor page). Is there a cleaner way to do this instead of just two nested foreach's?

```
<div class="container">
        @foreach (var track in tracks)
        {
            <SpeakerTrack track-name="@track">
                @foreach (var speaker in Model.Where(a => a.TrackName == track).
                     OrderBy(a => a.UserLastName))
                {
                    <Speaker speaker="@speaker"></Speaker>
                }
            </SpeakerTrack>
        }
</div>
```

Comment: You can query your data in controller instead of second foreach , something like `var speaker in Model.Items` . `foreach` loop seems to be the cleaner way to do this.

Comment: Share us your model defination for `track` and `Model`.